# Advanced indexing in xarray, non orthogonal

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

I would like to select few points from a `DataArray`, in a similar manner as can be done in numpy (`arr_np[:, x_idxs, y_idxs]`), but it seems that advanced indexing in `xarray` differs from advanced indexing in `numpy`.

I think it comes from the fact that `xarray` always do orthogonal indexing (as called in the ["Vectorized Indexing"](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/indexing.html#vectorized-indexing) section of the documentation.

Let's say I have the following array:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

import xarray as xr
import numpy as np


sizes = {"band": 4, "x": 5, "y": 6}
shape = tuple(sizes.values())
dims = tuple(sizes.keys())

arr_np = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
arr_xr = xr.DataArray(
    data=arr_np,
    dims=dims,
    coords={
        "band": np.arange(100, 100 + sizes["band"]),
        "x": list(ascii_lowercase[: sizes["x"]]),  # abcde...
        "y": list(ascii_uppercase[: sizes["y"]]),  # ABCDE...
    },
)
```

```py
>>> arr_xr
<xarray.DataArray (band: 4, x: 5, y: 6)>
array([[[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
        [  6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11],
        [ 12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17],
        [ 18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23],
        [ 24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29]],

       ...

       [[ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95],
        [ 96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101],
        [102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107],
        [108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113],
        [114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]]])
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int64 100 101 102 103
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'
  * y        (y) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F'
```

and I want to sample the following points (here formatted in any way I can think of that could be used):

```py
points = [("a", "C"), ("d", "D"), ("e", "A")]
points_idxs = [(0, 2), (3, 3), (4, 0)]

xs, ys = map(list, zip(*points))  # ['a', 'd', 'e'] and ['C', 'D', 'A']
x_idxs, y_idxs = map(list, zip(*points_idxs))  # [0, 3, 4] and [2, 3, 0]
```

In numpy I can just do:

```py
expected = arr_np[:, x_idxs, y_idxs]
assert expected.shape == (sizes["band"], len(points))
```

```py
>>> expected
array([[  2,  21,  24],
       [ 32,  51,  54],
       [ 62,  81,  84],
       [ 92, 111, 114]])
```

But doing so over the `DataArray` does not produce the same output:

```py
>>> # Same output for the 3 ways
>>> arr_xr.loc[:, xs, ys]
>>> arr_xr.sel(x=xs, y=ys)
>>> arr_xr[:, x_idxs, y_idxs]
<xarray.DataArray (band: 4, x: 3, y: 3)>
array([[[  2,   3,   0],
        [ 20,  21,  18],
        [ 26,  27,  24]],

       [[ 32,  33,  30],
        [ 50,  51,  48],
        [ 56,  57,  54]],

       [[ 62,  63,  60],
        [ 80,  81,  78],
        [ 86,  87,  84]],

       [[ 92,  93,  90],
        [110, 111, 108],
        [116, 117, 114]]])
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int64 100 101 102 103
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'd' 'e'
  * y        (y) <U1 'C' 'D' 'A'
```

How can I get the expected output ?

Comment: I wonder if you have to, in someway, turn off the labels in the `arr_xr` case to get the `expect`.   Expected is the diagonals of the  `arr_xr[:, x_idxs, y_idxs]`, result, with `band` coordinates, but no `x,y` ones.  I don't see an example on the documentation link.

Comment: I found some examples using `isel` to do the 'point wise' indexing you want'  They define a new dimension, e.g. 'z' or 'p' to replace your 'x,'y'.  MATLAB requiores the use of `sub2ind` to select the kind of 'diagonals' that numpy finds 'naturally'.

Comment: Nice catch about the diagonal, didn't notice that. Yeah I kind of found out about introducing a new dimension (see answer), because it's like xarray doesn't allow the indexing to reduce the number of dimension as numpy does. However I only made it work for `sel` not `isel`, where did you find those examples ?

Comment: I'm also wondering if I can make good use of ["`DataArray` objects as indexers"](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing).

Comment: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.isel.html#xarray.DataArray.isel

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks a lot, didn't notice the doc for `sel` and `isel` adress point wise selection. So the solution does involves DataArrays as indexers, see answer if interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to do it using hints by @hpaulj, using `DataArray` as indexers, introducing a new dimension "pos" on the `result` array.

Using the variables defined in the question.

**Index based indexing**

```py
# x_idxs, y_idxs = [0, 3, 4], [2, 3, 0]

# Using DataArray object as indexer
x_idxs_da = xr.DataArray(x_idxs, dims=["pos"])
y_idxs_da = xr.DataArray(y_idxs, dims=["pos"])

result = arr_xr.isel(x=x_idxs_da, y=y_idxs_da)
assert np.all(result.data == expected)

result = arr_xr[:, x_idxs_da, y_idxs_da]
assert np.all(result.data == expected)

# Or annotated tuple to be implicitly converted to DataArray indexer
result = arr_xr.isel(x=("pos", x_idxs), y=("pos", y_idxs))
assert np.all(result.data == expected)

result = arr_xr[:, ("pos", x_idxs), ("pos", y_idxs)]
assert np.all(result.data == expected)
```

**Coordinate based indexing**

```py
# xs, ys = ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['C', 'D', 'A']

# Using DataArray object as indexer
xs_da = xr.DataArray(xs, dims=["pos"])
ys_da = xr.DataArray(ys, dims=["pos"])

result = arr_xr.sel(x=xs_da, y=ys_da)
assert np.all(result.data == expected)

result = arr_xr.loc[:, xs_da, ys_da]
assert np.all(result.data == expected)

# Can't use implicit conversion
# result = arr_xr.sel(x=("pos", xs), y=("pos", ys))  # InvalidIndexError
# result = arr_xr.loc[:, ("pos", xs), ("pos", ys)]  # InvalidIndexError
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed achieving it using `.stack()`, but only using the `.sel()` method, so didn't achieve it using index based indexing.

```py
>>> points
[('a', 'C'), ('d', 'D'), ('e', 'A')]
>>> arr_xr.stack(pos=("x", "y")).loc[:, points]  # or
>>> arr_xr.stack(pos=("x", "y")).sel(pos=points)
<xarray.DataArray (band: 4, pos: 3)>
array([[  2,  21,  24],
       [ 32,  51,  54],
       [ 62,  81,  84],
       [ 92, 111, 114]])
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int64 100 101 102 103
  * pos      (pos) object MultiIndex
  * x        (pos) <U1 'a' 'd' 'e'
  * y        (pos) <U1 'C' 'D' 'A'
```

Not working for index based indexing, so question still open:

```py
>>> arr_xr.stack(pos=("x", "y")).isel(pos=points_idxs)  # or
>>> arr_xr.stack(pos=("x", "y"))[:, points_idxs]
IndexError: Unlabeled multi-dimensional array cannot be used for indexing: pos
```